# entityManagerFactory not initialized

Tags: spring, jpa-2.0, liferay-6, hibernate-entitymanager

i'm creating a portlet to load in liferay 6.2.
The portlet is a spring portlet with it's own db and uses jpa.

My pom is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>it.realt</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyPos</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>MyPos Portlet</name>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <!-- original spring version 3.0.7.RELEASE -->
        <spring.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <liferay.maven.plugin.version>6.2.10.15</liferay.maven.plugin.version>
        <liferay.version>6.2.4</liferay.version>
        <liferay.auto.deploy.dir>C:\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga5\deploy</liferay.auto.deploy.dir>
        <liferay.app.server.deploy.dir>C:\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga5\tomcat-7.0.62\webapps</liferay.app.server.deploy.dir>
        <liferay.app.server.lib.global.dir>C:\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga5\tomcat-7.0.62\lib\ext</liferay.app.server.lib.global.dir>
        <liferay.app.server.portal.dir>C:\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga5\tomcat-7.0.62\webapps\ROOT</liferay.app.server.portal.dir>
    </properties>        
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.liferay.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>liferay-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${liferay.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-css</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <autoDeployDir>${liferay.auto.deploy.dir}</autoDeployDir>
                    <appServerDeployDir>${liferay.app.server.deploy.dir}</appServerDeployDir>
                    <appServerLibGlobalDir>${liferay.app.server.lib.global.dir}</appServerLibGlobalDir>
                    <appServerPortalDir>${liferay.app.server.portal.dir}</appServerPortalDir>
                    <liferayVersion>${liferay.version}</liferayVersion>
                    <pluginType>portlet</pluginType>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>portal-service</artifactId>
            <version>${liferay.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>util-bridges</artifactId>
            <version>${liferay.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>util-taglib</artifactId>
            <version>${liferay.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>util-java</artifactId>
            <version>${liferay.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.portlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>portlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId> 
            <version>${spring.version}</version> 
        </dependency> 
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId> 
            <version>${spring.version}</version> 
        </dependency>
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> 
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId> 
            <version>5.0.6.Final</version> 
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>        

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.java-persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jpa-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.Beta-20090815</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.6.Final</version> 
        </dependency>                
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.13</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.13</version>
        </dependency>    


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
        </dependency>     
       <!--   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>--> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.8</version>
        </dependency>  

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0-b01</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava-collections</artifactId>
            <version>r03</version>
        </dependency>           

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

my spring configuration for the portlet is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.0.xsd"
>
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="it.realt.*" />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />


    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
          p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory" />

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
              class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
              p:dataSource-ref="businessDataSource" p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="jpaAdapter"
              p:packagesToScan="it.realt.mypos.domain" >
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
            <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="connection.autoReconnect">true</prop>
                <prop key="connection.autoReconnectForPools">true</prop>
                <prop key="connection.is-connection-validation-required">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaAdapter" 
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" 
          p:database="POSTGRESQL" p:showSql="true" />

    <bean id="bgdApplicationContextProvider" 
          class="it.realt.mypos.util.ApplicationContextProvider" />     

    <bean name="businessDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" >
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/myPos" />
        <property name="username" value="xxxx" />
        <property name="password" value="xxx" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I Have an abstract class using generics as base for DAO classes, and i'm injecting EntityManager using @PersistenceContext

```
public abstract class DaoImpl<T extends Serializable, K> implements Dao<T, K> {

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager em;

    private Class<T> type;
.......
```

When liferay server starts and try to load my portlet,  i'm getting an error in initializing the EntityManagerFactory

```
    13:49:22,583 WARN  [XmlPortletApplicationContext:546] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in PortletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-context/portlet/MyPos-portlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
    13:49:22,583 ERROR [DispatcherPortlet:279] Context initialization failed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in PortletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-context/portlet/MyPos-portlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
        at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.createPortletApplicationContext(FrameworkPortlet.java:368)
        at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.initPortletApplicationContext(FrameworkPortlet.java:297)
        at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.initPortletBean(FrameworkPortlet.java:271)
        at org.springframework.web.portlet.GenericPortletBean.init(GenericPortletBean.java:124)
        at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.init(GenericPortlet.java:136)
.......
```

what's wrong? Maybe I forgot something in my configuration?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a JPA2.1 provider (Hibernate 5.0.6) with a beta version of the JPA 2.0 library in your classpath (2.0.Beta-20090815). So the provider tries calling a method which doesn't exist yet: `Table.indexes()`.

Use the JPA 2.1 library.

Comment: I think also some maven excludes will be needed